# JQuery - найти элемент по тексту

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно найти элемент на странице по значению текста. Есть селектор `contains`, но он ищет по сути вхождение подстроки в строку. То есть, например, есть элементы `<a>новый игрок</a>` и `<a>игрок</a>`. Нужно найти элемент с текстом "игрок". Так вот, contains вернет в качестве результата оба этих элемента, а нужно получить только последний. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: модификатор указать и искать по нему

Comment: Без этого никак?

Comment: с этим вам будет проще, если вы захотите в будущем поменять поиск, то вам нужно будет просто переставить модификатор, а не переписывать js функцию, к тому же вдруг вы захотите сделать мультиязычность на всех языках мира (к примеру)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var findText = "player";
var $elements = $(".container *").filter(function(){
  return $(this).html() == findText;
});
// or ... = $(".container span").filter(... if only specific type of elements is needed

console.log("Found", $elements.length, "element[s].")
$elements.each(function() { console.log(this); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span>new player</span>
  <div><span>player</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: А не будет бобо и вава, на реальной странице с тысячами элементов?)

Comment: вот и я так же подумал. ляжет все. пройденный этап)